# Story about boy cocooned by giant wolf spiders for food

Tags: story-identification, horror

A friend remembers a horror story in which giant spiders had overrun the world and a little boy was cocooned as food for hungry baby wolf spiders.

Comment: Can you see if you can get any of the details suggested by [How to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407)?  The timeframe of the story, where he read it, anything like that would help.

Comment: This question would be improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Did it involve him waking up from a nightmare with spiders, only to realize he was waking up in a cocoon?

Comment: It was in a scary short story collection.

Answer (score 4):

The story is probably "The Itsy Bitsy Spider" by F. Paul Wilson.  IT appeared in his collection "Aftershock and Others" from 2009. It's the same one you're thinking of FuzzyBoots.

[image]

Comment: Ah, the book does look familiar. I got on an F. Paul Wilson kick after reading his Repairman Jack series.

Comment: Wilson is great.  Surprised he doesn't have a bigger fanbase.